# How to connect a Roland EG-101 headphone output jack to a computer to record input?

Tags: input

Beginner audio question: I have a Roland EG-101 from the year 1999 and I want to connect it to my computer for direct recording and mixing but I don't know how to do this.  The Roland has a MIDI output and a headphones output.
Is there a device I need to buy to do this? I have a Tascam DR40 if that`s useful at all here.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the manual, you should have a stereo line output via two RCA sockets. These would be the ones I would be using. You need an RCA to line level cable. The line level end is likely to be a 3.5mm stereo TRS jack which you should connect to your computer's line in socket. If you don't have a usable line in socket then you can buy a simple USB audio interface from ebay for next to nothing which will have the appropriate line in port.